# Unable to locate the login box by type attribute or xpath

Tags: selenium, testing, xpath, automation

HTML looks like following

```
<input class="text-input text-input-md" dir="auto" ng-reflect-klass="text-input" ng-reflect-ng-class="text-input-md" type="email" aria-labelledby="lbl-14" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="" ng-reflect-type="email">
```

the code fails to find login box...tried by attribute

```
var email_xpath = "//*[type='email']"
```

then xpath

```
var email_xpath = "/html/body/ion-app/ng-component/ion-split-pane/ion-nav/page-login/ion-content/div[2]/ion-list/ion-item[1]/div[1]/div/ion-input/input"
var email = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(email_xpath))
```

but still unable to get the element....

===============Updated===============

most of the solutions posted below works with selenium firefox driver. The issue was really with htmlunit driver that i was using in scala. Probably it cannot handle javascript properly. I changed it with firefox driver and your solutions works well. The application being tested is an Ionic app (angular), hence i will have to look for another headless solution later.

Comment: Are you actually using Watir? Seems unusual given the methods such as `findElement`.

Answer (score 2):

`//*[type='email']` is not correct XPath. Try below instead:

```
//*[@type='email']
```

Note that `type='email'` predicate means child node with string value `'email'`:

```
<input>
    <type>email</type>
</input>
```

While `@type='email'` means *attribute `type` with value `"email"`*

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct but You can try this also `//input[@type='email']`

Comment: I'm quite sure that only `input` HTML node can have `type="email"` attribute, so specifying tag name in this case makes no improvement actually

Answer (score 1):

The generic syntax is something like as mentioned below for xpath

1. // - means relative xpath, can be present anywhere inside DOM
2. tagName - means html tags like td,tr,span,br,input etc
3. @- denotes start of attribute name present inside html tag
4. value - actual attribute value present inside DOM

   ```
    //tagName[@attribute='value']
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any XPath, as some are already mentioned by @Andersson and @zsbappa

some others are

```
//input[@class='text-input text-input-md' and @type='email']
//input[contains(@type,'email')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WATIR, you don't have to write xpath, write the below code, it would work.

```
b.text_field(type: "email").set "abc@gmail.com"
```